# after_destroy not called for linked table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_functions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :functions, :through => :user_functions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :functions, allow_destroy: true
```

Model of the linked table:

```
class UserFunction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_functions
  belongs_to :function, inverse_of: :user_functions
  after_destroy :unplan_items
  after_create :plan_items
```

and of course the model of function but this is like user...

Now when I do the following in my tests:

```
@user.functions = [@functions]
@user.save
expect(@user.planned_items.count).to eq(1)
@user.functions = []
@user.save
```

I notice the callback after_destroy isn't called.  Why is this and how can I avoid this.  There are certain steps that need to be done every time a UserFunction is destroyed...

I believe this has to do with: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7618 (I'm using rails 4.2.5 though).  The after_create is working perfect though...

Comment: Setting an instance variable to [] and then saving it is not the same as calling destroy.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you.  The @user refers to a certain user which has 3 functions linked to him through the user_functions table.  setting functions to [] effectively deletes these records (user_functions).  Why doesn't this go through the destroy of those?

Answer (score 4):

Currently rails uses :delete_all as default strategy of has_many_through. It only calls `:destroy_all` when we explicitly specify `dependent: :destroy` on the association.

The docs mention advice to use has_many `:through` if you need callbacks:
   See the suggestion here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

So there currently is an inconsistency between `after_create` which does do the callback and `after_destroy`.

This is mentioned in these two issues posted on GitHub:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7618

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27099

The fix for now is to explicitly put `:dependent => :destroy` on the `:through` part.  This will make sure the callback are used.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_functions
  has_many :functions, :through => :user_functions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :functions, allow_destroy: true
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this 2021+

Change This

```
has_many :object_tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :tags, :through => :object_tags
```

To This

```
has_many :object_tags
has_many :tags, :through => :object_tags, :dependent => :destroy
```